# Is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut that acts as an on/off switch?

Tags: power-management

I just got a RaspberryPi and I'm completely new to linux and all the intricate details of programming. My issue with the RaspberryPi is the difficulty with turning it on and off. After doing some research, it seems that there are boards out there that can do this, but I already have a wireless keyboard and would not like to purchase another accessory if I don't need to. The keyboard has a pc power button, which works with my laptop but obviously not the pi. is there any way to program a keyboard shortcut of some kind to turn it into a functioning on/off switch? or do I have to buy the board?

Comment: Have you searched this forum for the many related questions?  Why do you want to turn it off - the Pi draws less power than most appliances on standby?

Answer (score 13):

The main issue is the fact that the RaspberryPi's hardware design actually does not offer a power-off circuitry. So the answer is that without additional hardware it is not possible to power the RaspberryPi down using that keyboard button.

While the keyboard event could certainly be used to `halt` the system that would do no good as power consumption is only barely reduced and furthermore there is no inherent way to turn it back on again (without additional hardware that is).

Answer (score 6):

You will need peripheral hardware to turn the pi on and off, since it does not have a power button. The good news is that it is fairly simple to build one, and not very expensive. Have a look at: http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2013/01/Adding-an-On-Off-switch-to-your-Raspberry-Pi